# Is damage caused to an engine by a Spark Plug an " external influence"?

Tags: engine, mercedes-benz

My knowledge of engines is poor. How do I continue the fight for a warranty claim?

Merc C180
Year Model: 2019
Mileage:  42 000km’s
Diagnosis:
•   Vehicle misfiring usually indicates a fuel / combustion concern.  For this reason a fuel test was requested.
•   The fuel test passed the SANS specifications and therefore indicating that the concern was in the engine itself.
•   The Dealer was instructed to remove the cylinder head where it was found that a piece of metal has damaged the bore and cylinder head.
•   The metal piece found is similar to that of a spark plug end, however, all the spark plugs on the vehicle are intact, indicating that the spark plug might have been replaced.  We have no record of this being done on our system.
•   The metal piece and a spark plug is on route to Metallurgist in CT to analyse and provide feedback.  The purpose is to determine the composition of the metal piece.

In conclusion:

- No record of spark plug change on this vehicle by any of our dealerships – no claim submitted.
- Metal piece caused damage to the cylinder bore resulting in the need for a complete engine replacement.
- Cost of repair cannot be claimed under Warranty & Maintenance as cause of damage is classified as ‘external influence’.

Comment: An electrode off a spark plug could have caused the damage, if that is what you want to know.

Comment: @HandyHowie All spark plugs are in tact! So where could the metal have come from?

Comment: Well, they say that a sparkplug broke and somebody (not them) changed them afterwards. Thats their way out of responsability. Perhaps you could wait from the results of the lab? If it is viable to challenge their way-out-strategy in court, could better be answered in law.se or by a lawyer..

Comment: Just because the dealer didn't change the spark plugs, doesn't mean they weren't changed at some point.  There is a possibility that the part found in the combustion chamber was present from original assembly but how do you prove this?  At 42K km I'm sure the spark plugs didn't need replacement under periodic maint. yet.  What's the history on this vehicle?  Are you the original owner or was it pre-owned?  Did you have it serviced exclusively at MB dealers or has it been serviced by others?

Comment: @Martin Ok let us assume it is a piece of spark plug that damaged the vehicle. How is a damage caused by spark plug  deemed an "outside influence" ? A spark plug is an integral part of the engine.

Comment: @jwh20 Serviced exclusively at Merc Dealer.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If you want to pursue this, litigation will be required. Proving the manufacturer is at fault will be near impossible. If it is spark plug "guts" which did the deed, they are exactly right if there's nothing in their system showing it was changed by MB. "Outside influence" means, something/someone other than a registered MB service provider did "the work" on the vehicle which caused the damage. As Martin stated, this resolves them of responsibility in their eyes. Proving otherwise is going to be impossible.

Comment: @Anthony They might argue that the defective spark plug got installed by somebody other than a mercedes dealership. They back it by stating that all present spark plugs are fine, combined with the fact that the foreign object is a piece of a sparkplug, there must happened a intervention by somebody else.

Unless you have a receipt of an recent sparkplug replacement, I see bad for your case. But I am not an lawyer..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about legal responsibility and not maintenance.

Comment: I feel your pain @Anthony, but you should be talking to a lawyer.

Comment: If you have a service agreement plan, and the car is under warranty, then *why* would anyone have changed a spark plug and not recorded the fact? M-B must have a pretty strong reason to suspect that someone inexpert has tampered with the engine, or it's BS.

Comment: @WeatherVane because if you are 500 miles away from home (and maybe even in a foreign country) with a cylinder not firing, you want it fixed RIGHT NOW, and you don't care about warranty claims if you (or somebody else) can fit a new plug in five minutes, and it only costs you $20 for the parts and labour.

Comment: I was thinking about what else the bit in question might be other than the electrode of a spark plug.  Another thing that it could be is a piece of piston ring that has broken off.  If that turns out to be the case, it would make a good argument that it's a defect instead of "external influence".

Comment: Clearly the first step is to find out what the foreign object actually is. I would expect metallurgy could tell the difference between a spark plug tip and something else. If it *is* a plug tip, the only options are (1) *somebody* changed the plug or (2) somehow the plug tip was inside the engine from new, which isn't very plausible if damage only occurred after 42000 km.

Comment: Also, note that the "SANS speciifications" are a *South African* spec, and the OP's profile says "Johannesburg". Any assumptions about motoring and car repair standards and practices in the USA or Europe are probably irrelevant.

Comment: @alephzero is that a hint that the dealership might apply to M-B for a warranty repair and pocket the fee from the customer?

Comment: @alephzero Vehicle was serviced at 38,604 kilometres at a MB dealer .  Is it possible that the metal piece was left inside from when the spark plugs were last changed?